# Is it completely safe to install java plug-in chrome browser?

Tags: security, java, plugins

I wonder if one of you have some information about the safety of Java in browsers. It is the built-in version of Java which chrome offers to install in browser. Is there any difference between installing Java on your Operating system and installing it on browser (for security issues)?

Comment: It is not completely safe to use a browser — any browser. It is not completely safe to have network connectivity, either.

Answer (score 1):

They're both the Java JRE AFAIK. No big difference there.  When an applet is run in a browser, it has limited security permissions which you can edit manually.

I don't think there is any difference in the packages through the browser or through Java.com.  I'm pretty sure they're the same thing.  Either way, security settings will be the same.